# "Dark mode" on Laravel 6 exception page

Tags: laravel, web-deployment, laravel-6

[image]

How to activate "Dark mode" in Laravel 6 Ignition (exception page)?

Comment: follow
https://flareapp.io/docs/ignition-for-laravel/installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add this line to your .env file :

```
IGNITION_THEME=dark
```

Answer (score 6):

Publish the config files if not already exists.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider" --tag="ignition-config"
```

Then, in the `config/ignition.php` set `'theme' => env('IGNITION_THEME', 'dark'),`

Answer (score 5):

As per the Laravel 6 Ignition documentation. You can activate it by changing `theme` key of the ignition `config file` from `light` to `dark`

> You can configure a theme in the theme key of the ignition `config file`. Out of the box there are two beautiful themes supported named `light` and `dark`

[Ignition for Laravel -> Configuration -> Theme support](https://flareapp.io/docs/ignition-for-laravel/configuration)